# Red Object In Autodesk Maya Extention 2 Workplace?

Tags: maya

I install Maya 2016 Extension 2 , but i can't use it, because an red object on workplace ! 
In Maya 2016 ( without Extension 2 ) i don't have any problem.

[image]

Comment: You should talk to autodesk support, I don't think so its really a programming question ??

Comment: i solved the problem by update VGA cart to last version.